# Format DATETIME column using PHP after printing

Tags: php, mysql

Hey, I am using DATETIME for my column for my database. I am trying to find the best way to format this date held in the row using PHP. I tried using date() but that would just print the current date. My row looks something like:

```
$row['date_added']
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple options.

1. Use MySQL's [DATE_FORMAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) function to format it.
2. Use MySQL's [UNIX_TIMESTAMP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp) function to get a timestamp PHP's [date](http://php.net/date)() function can play with.
3. Run the MySQL DATETIME through PHP's [strtotime](http://php.net/strtotime)() function to get a timestamp PHP's date() function can play with.

As an example of #3:

```
print date('<format string>', strtotime($row['date_added']));
```

Just follow the documentation on date() to construct a format string to your liking and swap it in.

Comment: Would i have something like this: strtotime($row['date_started'])

Comment: That'll get you a timestamp to use in the second argument of date(), yes.

Comment: Like so?
strtotime($row['date_started'],date("m/d/y"))

Comment: Other way around. date('m/d/y', strtotime($row['date_started'])). See updated answer.