# PHP converting date format

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

> ### Duplicate
>
> - [Managing date formats differences between PHP and MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415092/managing-date-formats-differences-between-php-and-mysql)
> - [PHP/MySQL: Convert from YYYY-MM-DD to DD Month, YYYY?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/744010/php-mysql-convert-from-yyyy-mm-dd-to-dd-month-yyyy)
> - [Format DATETIME column using PHP after printing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/668735/format-datetime-column-using-php-after-printing)
> - [date formatting in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/638011/date-formatting-in-php/638022)

Dear All,

I have a PHP page where i wil be displaying some data from Mysql db.
I have 2 dates to display on this page.In my db table, Date 1 is in the format d/m/Y (ex: 11/11/2002) and Date 2 is in the format d-m-Y (ex : 11-11-2002)
I need to display both of this in the same format .The format i have stored in a variable $dateFormat='m/d/Y'

Can any one guide me

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `strtotime` to convert the strings into a Unix timestamp, then use the `date` function to generate the correct output format.

Since you're using the UK date format "d/m/Y", and strtotime expects a US format, you need to convert it slighly differently:

```
$date1 = "28/04/2009";
$date2 = "28-04-2009";

function ukStrToTime($str) {
    return strtotime(preg_replace("/^([0-9]{1,2})[\/\. -]+([0-9]{1,2})[\/\. -]+([0-9]{1,4})/", "\\2/\\1/\\3", $str));
}

$date1 = date($dateFormat, ukStrToTime($date1));
$date2 = date($dateFormat, ukStrToTime($date2));
```

Comment: When i pass "28/04/2009 " to the above mentioned method, i am getting "01/01/70"

Comment: I hadn't noticed that you were using UK time. I've updated my example.

Comment: Its not "UK time", it is "not weird US date formats". Pretty much the rest of the world use dd/mm/yyyy see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calendar_date#dd.2Fmm.2Fyyyy_or_dd.mm.yyyy_.28day.2C_month.2C_year.29. ;)

Comment: I would have thought PHP would use the locale setting for its default date order, as in setlocale().  It'd be disappointing if it didn't.

Comment: Oooh apparently there is an alternative to strtotime when you want locale taken into account: http://au2.php.net/manual/en/function.strptime.php

Comment: The reason I didn't mention strptime is that it isn't available on Windows platforms.

Answer (score 2):

You should be all set with this:

```
echo date($dateFormat, strtotime($date1));
echo date($dateFormat, strtotime($date2));
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look into the [strptime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strptime.php) function.  This can convert any date from a string back into numeric values.  Unlike [strtotime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php), it can be adapted to different formats, including those from different locales, and its output is not a UNIX timestamp, so it's capable of parsing dates before 1970 and after 2037.  It may be a little bit more work though because it returns an associative array though.

Unfortunately it's not available on Windows systems either so it's not portable.

Answer (score 0):

If for some reason strtotime will not work for you, could always just replace the offending punctuation with str_replace.

```
function dateFormat($date) {
$newDate = str_replace(/, -, $date);
echo $newDate;
}

echo dateFormat($date1);
echo dateFormat($date2);
```

I know this will make most folks cringe, but it may help you with formatting non-date strings in the future.

Comment: str_replace expects strings, you're missing quotes.

Answer (score 0):

rookie i am. so came up with the method that just do that. what mysql needs.. shish i used param 2... hope it helps. regards

```
public function dateConvert($date,$param){  
     if($param==1){  
         list($day,$month,$year)=split('[/.-]',$date);  
         $date="$year-$month-$day"; //changed this line  
         return $date;  
     }  
     if ($param == 2){ //output conversion  
            list($day,$month,$year) = split('[/.]', $date);  
            $date = "$year-$day-$month";  
            return $date;  
   }  
 }
```