# converting date format from 0000-00-00 to timestamp

Tags: php

I have a date picker that returns date in the format 0000-00-00 with

```
$startT = isset($_POST["startT"]) ? $_POST["startT"] : "";
```

how do I convert this formatted date into a timestamp?
Thanks

Comment: 0000-00-00 is not a date format...

Comment: @Juhana: I think we can safely assume he means `yyyy-mm-dd`

Comment: Is the jQuery UI datepicker? You can change the date format: http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#option-dateFormat.

Comment: Yes thank you it does. I'd like to convert it into a time stamp, or extract (for example) yyyy

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP converting date format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/775758/php-converting-date-format)

Answer (score 5):

If you have PHP 5.3, which you should, the easiest way is:

```
$timestamp = new DateTime($_POST['startT']);
$timestamp->getTimestamp();
```

Comment: I'm planning to migrate upto it when I get my new server.  I realise I should but this has to happen first!

Answer (score 2):

Use strtotime() which works pretty fine in most cases

```
$time = strtotime($_POST['startT']);
```

Comment: Sadly it appears not to. 2010-01-01 is converting into a timestamp of dec 31 2009 23:00

Comment: That just means you use the incorrect timezone when displaying it as a date again...

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is

```
echo mktime($_POST["startT"]);
```